# Active Record Relation with Postgres and Devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, relationship, has-many

I'm trying to give a User Deeds.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :deeds
end

class Deed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

In Rails Console I get this error:  ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: user_id

Can someone please explain what's wrong with this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you get the error? Did you run migration (`rake db:migrate`)?

Comment: Do you have user_id column in deeds table?

Comment: this is the error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column deeds.user_id does not exist

Comment: I don't understand why it's asking for that... shouldnt activerecord assign a user_id if a deed belongs to user?  should I add_column :user_id in the deed class?

Comment: What's in your Deed migration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a column in the `Deed` model called `user_id`.  Rails will automatically populate that column with the ID of the user that the deed belongs to when you create the association (e.g. through `@deed.user = User.first`).

Once you have a `user_id` defined for each of your deeds, calling things like `@user.deeds` will allow Rails to do an SQL query that says "give me any deeds that have user_id equal to this user's ID".  Similarly, when you call `@deed.user`, Rails can issue an SQL query that says "give me the user with id equal to this deed's user_id".

Comment: Ok great I just tried that, but it gave me a new error NoMethodError: undefined method `add_column' for #<Class:0x007fe7dda31ed0>

Comment: You need to add a column in the database.  That means you need to run a migration to add a column to the `Deed` table.  You should probably take a couple steps back and read about migrations in Rails -- I think you will ultimately get through things faster that way.

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate... I don't know what I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you don't have a migration that adds the column you need, so running the other migrations doesn't do anything. You need to make a migration file to add the column you need, then run that.

Comment: class AddUserIdToDeed < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :deeds, :user_id, :string
  end
end
i ran this after doing rails g migration AddUserIdToDeed user_id:string... is that right?

Comment: @user2626712 it should be :user_id and as the name suggests it would be integer not string cuz it's an id.